# Has anyone figured out how to get numpy working?

Tags: python

I have followed a ton of so-called tutorials to get numpy working in Blender so the Animation Nodes will work without success.

Can anyone please tell us how to do this in simple laymans turms?

Comment: Numpy is included in the official builds available from blender.org since version 2.70. Are you using an older version of Blender?